# Windows Defender picks up Kali Linux's ISO. Is this normal or a real threat?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, kali-linux

I ran a full PC scan by windows defender and this thing comes up and isn't going even after pressing start actions. Please help me out.

[image: windows defender scan report]

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you running WSL2?

Comment: You've downloaded the Linux distro specifically for **penetration testing**. It can be considered "malware" by nature.

Comment: No. Not true at all. Downloads and installs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Kali ISO is full of malware - *by design.* So Windows Defender picking up malware contained within the .iso is normal.

However, to ensure the .iso has not been compromised, verify the hash of the .iso file against the one provided on the website.

Comment: In my experience with 4 years of Kali downloads from the kali.org legitimate website, that is simply not true.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

This is likely from leaving a spare Kali .iso on your machine.

**Longer answer:**

For Kali ISOs on Windows: if you leave the original .iso on your machine, Windows Defender may alert when you run a full scan. If you've deleted the .iso after setting up Kali (WSL, another machine, whatever), you shouldn't see these warnings.

Always verify a hash if it's possible before you start applying the iso, however.

If you want to test to ensure that it was the iso's presence itself (a Kali iso, specifically, will create a large number of security warnings upon scan): fully delete the .iso and re-run the full scan.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded numerous Kali ISO files both on a VMware machine and a Hyper-V machine.

I have the key ISO files store on my two machines.

Both are Windows 11 Pro and properly protected by Windows Defender.

I download Kali ISO ONLY from the legitimate Kali Download site.

No special whitelisting in WD.

No viruses of any kind over the last 4 years or so.

Just use the Kali site and you should be fine.

Purple is a specific variant of Kali - try the regular variant as it has the same main tools.

I have Kali 2023.1 machines running in both VMware and in Hyper-V with no virus issues at all.

**Followup Note:**

I had a spare moment, downloaded Kali 2023 Purple, and I am installing it in Hyper-V.

No issue with viruses.

**Kali (downloaded from kali.org) is not a virus.**